# Syntax of timestamp

Tags: codeigniter, timestamp

How do I insert values in a database field with type timestamp? I am doing this way in CodeIgniter.

```
$user_poll_query=array('description'=>$poll_query,
                       'creator_id'=>$user_id,
                       'valid_from'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s','1299762201428'),
                       );
$this->db->insert('sl_polls',$user_poll_query);
```

but in the database I am getting `0s (0000-00-00 00.00.00)`.

Comment: Its because that read as a string! Remove the quote : `'valid_from'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s',1299762201428),`

Comment: I have also done this but nothing is showing

Comment: `'valid_from'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like you are using

```
'valid_from'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s','1299762201428'),
```

but your date isn't in the format Y-m-d H:i:s.

Try a different date format or convert the UNIX timestamp to a date your db can use.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually i am seraching but dont understand this kind of format like what this number represents i mean how 1299762201428 represents a year month etc. can you explain

Comment: It looks like a unix timestamp, google it to learn how to convert.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you are using MS SQL Server, I think that your problem is that you don't get the idea of a timestamp type in SQL Server. This isn't a "real" time. A Timestamp is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. timestamp is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime data type.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx

You should use a Date, Time, or DateTime field to track when something was done.

hth

Mike Irwin